# Conditionally filtering out a value that shows up mutiple times with r/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to know how to filter out a value that shows up multiple times if in one of the instances, it meets a specific condition.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c),
                 y = c(73,6,6,10,10,10,4,4,4))

x  y
a 73
a 6
a 6
b 10
b 10
b 10
c 4 
c 4
c 4
```

Since `73` appears once under `y` in row 1 when `x` is also equals to `a`, how would I go about filtering all of the times when `x = a`?

I have tried `group_by()` before filtering but I still see a appear. Another additional question is that if there is a missing value in the y col, how would I also go about keeping it in the same filter pipe since filter would also drop N/As?

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    filter(y != 73)
```

Comment: Include the output you want

Answer (score 0):

Using `any` or with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  filter((!73 %in% y)|is.na(y), .by = 'x')
```